# how to get the resultset from a camel jpa component?

Tags: jpa, apache-camel

on querying a camle jpa component like

```
<from uri="jpa:jpa.camel?consumer.query=select x from jpa.camel x"/>

<to uri="bean:SomeBean?method=query" />
```

how do u get the list of records from camel exchange in the bean ? i have tried casting as List ,Resultset objects .but i get a ClassCastException .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get one entity at a time. So if the query returns 5 rows, then 5 exchanges are created and published from the jpa consumer. So the bean will then be invoked 5 times, one for each exchange.

Comment: is there anyway can i change the consumer.query dynmacially i mean in <from uri="jpa:jpa.camel?consumer.query=Some-query"/> i want to change the Some-query part during runtime . for this to be done do i need to use Java DSL routes also along with the spring xml ? can i use them both ?

Comment: No the from XXX is static, once its been created and started

Comment: You will have to create a new route if you want to change the SELECT on the JPA consumer. CamelContext has API for stopping and adding new routes. Check out chapter 13 in the Camel in Action book as well.